# Weighted sampling in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame `data`. At each row `i` have assigned a weight that is in `data$ww`.
Now I would like to make a sample `new_data` of  `data`, weighted by `df$ww`.
I have tried with `subset` but it very slow.

```
# sample data
data <- data.frame(var1 = log(sample(1:5000)))
ndata <- nrow(data)
maxW <- max(data$var1)

nsample <- 4000
rr <- runif(ndata)
data$ww <- cumsum(exp(data$var1))
new_data <- data[0, ]
i <- 1
while(nrow(new_data) < nsample) {
  new_data[i, ] <- subset(data, data$ww > rr[i] * maxW)[1,]
  i <- i + 1
}
```

Is there a faster way?

Comment: Are you sure you want to weight by `ww`? Your code seems to weight according to `var1`.

Comment: I am trying different transformation of the weight in var1.

Comment: Yes, but don't you want to weight by `exp(data$var1)` here? At least this is what your code does.

Comment: It is a quick and dirty version of roulette algorithm. Anyway thanx for the answer.

Comment: Yes, but your code does **not** weight by `ww`. The main problem with this code is that it is **wrong**, not that it is slow.

Comment: Why is this question heavily downvoted?

Answer (score 26):

Use the `prob` argument of `sample()`:

```
samp_idx <- sample(seq_len(nrow(data)), nsample, prob=data$ww)
new_data <- data[samp_idx, ]
```

Something like this. Running time is

```
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.015   0.000   0.014
```

versus your version:

```
# user  system elapsed 
# 4.278   0.007   4.290
```