# Sampling Random Points Closer to Today?

Tags: r, sample

I have this dataset in R:

```
date = sample(seq(as.Date('2015-01-01'), as.Date('2022-08-12'), by = "day"), 1000)
var1 = rnorm(1000, 1000,1000)
var2 = rnorm(1000, 1000,1000)
var3 = rnorm(1000, 1000,1000)

question_data = data.frame(date, var1, var2, var3)
question_data$id = 1:nrow(question_data)
```

I want to take 1000 random samples from this data such that "there are more points closer to today's date compared to the starting date".

I thought of a very simple way to do this - first, I order this dataset by date:

```
question_data <- question_data[order(-question_data$date),]
```

Then, I create a new "date_id":

```
question_data$date_id = 1:nrow(question_data)
```

From here, I choose an arbitrary cut-off and arbitrarily take weighted samples:

```
part_1 <- question_data[which(question_data$date_id > 750), ]
part_2 <- question_data[which(question_data$date_id < 750), ]


library(dplyr) 
 random_sample = data.frame(sample_n(part_1, 250, replace = TRUE), sample_n(part_2, 500, replace = TRUE))
```

- Is there a better way to do this? Perhaps some methods that might be able to perform "smooth" random samples?

Thank you!

Comment: It depends on what extent you want the sample skewed towards today. How much is "more" to you? That function can inform a new "weight" column (mathematically equivalent to or based on difference between that day and today), and the weight column can alter the random sampling.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25025994/weighted-sampling-in-r

Answer (score 1):

We can see the distribution of dates in the original data set if we do:

```r
hist(lubridate::year(question_data$date), breaks = 2014:2022 + 0.5)
```

[image]

If we want to sample the dates more frequently as they get closer to the current time, we can first arrange the data frame in date order:

```r
question_data <- question_data[order(question_data$date),]
```

Now, we can sample from all rows of the data frame, but we can specify the row number itself as a weighting, such that the probability of a particular row being selected goes from essentially 0 for row 1 to about 1 in 500 for the final row. Let's take a sample of 100 using this method and look at the histogram of dates:

```r
n <- 100

samp <- question_data[sample(seq(nrow(question_data)), n, replace = FALSE,
                             prob = seq(nrow(question_data))),]

hist(lubridate::year(samp$date), breaks = 2014:2022 + 0.5)
```

[image]